# Query selector attribute value starts with empty string fails

Tags: javascript, css-selectors

Can anyone explain why the following returns an empty list:

```
var el = document.createElement('div');
el.dataset.mydata="hello";
document.body.appendChild(el);
document.querySelectorAll('div[data-mydata^=""]');
```

(If you're wondering why you'd ever do this, the actual code is using a variable as the attribute value in the querySelector. The function it is part of gets called recursively, on the first run the variable is empty.)

Comment: because you are looking for an empty value. if you use `document.querySelectorAll('div[data-mydata^="hello"]');` it returns the element, yes?

Comment: @daddygames `^=` is a prefix check, not string equality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because [substring matching attribute selectors are dumb](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-3/#attribute-substrings):

> `[att^=val]`
>
> Represents an element with the `att` attribute whose value begins with the prefix "val". **If "val" is the empty string then the selector does not represent anything.**

(Emphasis mine.)

All substring selectors are broken by design: When given the empty string, they return nothing (instead of matching all strings). I have no idea why, but it's what the selector specification says.

The best fix is probably to add a check to your code that says *if `var` is empty, use `'div[data-mydata]'` instead* (i.e. only check for the presence of the attribute, not its value).

Comment: Thanks for answering the actual question. The solution you propose to the specific issue I was having was the workaround I was thinking of using as well. It's not quite as clean as if [att^=""] was equivalent to [att] but at least it works.

Comment: For better or for worse, the decision to make these attribute selectors with an empty value match nothing was [for simplicity and consistency with [att~=""\] from CSS2](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2008Apr/0032.html). I agree that this behavior is surprising to anyone who has worked with any substring matching function in any mainstream programming language, *especially* considering hardly anyone has even heard of [att~=val], much less used it.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement a condition that if the value is empty then to use `=` operator in selector and if value is not empty then use `^=` operator.

Try running following snippet

```js
var el = document.createElement('div');
var value = "";
el.dataset.mydata = value;
document.body.appendChild(el);
var elements = document.querySelectorAll(`div[data-mydata${value ? "^": ""}=""]`);
console.log(elements.length);
```

Comment: That only finds elements whose `data-mydata` attribute is equal to the empty string, not those that start with an empty string.

Comment: An attribute cannot start with a blank string if it has a value

Comment: Every string starts with an empty string. `/^/` matches everything.

Comment: But in case of attributes, it is not followed

Comment: css selectors are not a language, so you can't compare them with regular expressions

Comment: CSS selectors absolutely are a language. Even if they weren't, why couldn't I compare them?

Comment: because css never says selectors can use regular expressions